# jsp submit multiple select

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am working in JSP, which I am very new to, and trying to submit values from a select box that can select multiple values to an action class in Java.

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="ProjectIDs" listKey="projectID" listValue="name" id='lstBox2' style="min-width:150px">

</select>
```

At the moment I am able to select multiple values and pass the keys to a List variable called 'ProjectIDs' in my action class, which is what I want to do. But I would like to load all of the values in that select box without having to highlight them. This is because the values in the select box are loaded from another select box using javascript and a button that transfers the selected values from that select box to this one. So I shouldn't have to select the values in this select box because I always want to load ALL of them.

What is the easiest way to pre-select all of the values in the select box when I hit the submit button so that I don't have to highlight them myself?

Thank you! And sorry if my explanation was not very clear. I will further explain if this is the case.

Edit: I have made some changes in response to the answer provided. I am also using the Struts framework. So my select box starts out as an empty struts select box, which is then populated from the other struts select box.

```
<s:select list="#{}" multiple="true" name="ProjectIDs" listKey="projectID" listValue="name" id='lstBox2' style="min-width:150px"/>
```

Then in my form  tag I added this onsubmit function:

```
<s:form id="formMain" action="performancereport" theme="simple" method="get" onsubmit="selectAllOptions('lstbox2');">
```

And then finally this javascript function:

```
function selectAllOptions(selStr)
{
    var selObj = document.getElementById(selStr);
    for (var i=0; i<selObj.options.length; i++) {
        selObj.options[i].selected = true;
    }
}
```

However, I am still having the same problem. If I highlight all the options myself, it works fine, but it is not automatically selecting them for me when I hit the submit button.

Any suggestions?

Edit 2: RESOLVED.

Answer (score 1):

You can programatically select all the options using `javascript`:

```
var select = document.getElementById("lstBox2");
for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++)
{
    select.options[i].selected = true;
}
```

You can do this in your `onsubmit` function...right before you submit the `form`.

Comment: For some reason my solution is not working. Could you see if there's something wrong with the edits I made above? Thank you.

Comment: Did you do any debugging using browser tools to see where the problem is? Is there an error in the console? Is it making it into your `selectAllOptions()` function at all? Try to narrow down the problem using debugging tools then you will have a better idea of where to look...

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I did some debugging in chrome, and discovered that upon entering the selectAllOptions() function, the form has already been submitted and the page has been reset, so the select box is empty. So I somehow have to make the selectAllOptions() function occur before the submit. Isn't an onsubmit function in the form supposed to do this?

Comment: @Jriz908 What you can do is instead of creating a `submit` button for your form create a regular button then get rid of the `onsubmit` event on your `form` and move it to the `onclick` event of your button then do the above code and after that is done call this `document.forms['formMain'].submit();` to manually submit the form.  Make sure to set the `name="formMain"` on your form...

Comment: @Jriz908 you don't have to post an answer you could just mark mine as correct since you used the code to solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED:

I added this jQuery code to occur before the form is submitted.

```
$(function() {
    $('#formMain').submit(function() {
        var select = document.getElementById("lstBox2");
        for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++)
        {
            select.options[i].selected = true;
        }
        return true; 
    });
});
```